# Print button on CV is covered by text

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, stack-overflow-jobs

> [image]

This happens when I go to `stackoverflow.com/jobs/cv/edit/[my user id]` and click the <kbd>Preview Public CV</kbd> button. This is likely because of the CSS:

```
.cv.employer a.print {
    right: 0;
}
```

instead of being like other CVs being viewed as a non-employer, which have:

```
.cv-page .cv.public a.print {
    left: initial;
    right: -30px;
}
```

And additionally the employer's has a width of 715px:

```
.cv.employer {
    width: 715px;
    margin: 10px auto;
}
```

but the public's `.cv` is contained within `#content` that has a width of 685px and 15px of padding around that:

```
.cv-page #content {
    width: 685px;
}

#content {
    padding: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good catch! Thank you for the report!

For users *without a gravatar* the print button was getting meshed with the text and for users *with a gravatar* the print button was going incognito behind the gravatar. This is fixed now.